# Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let : $\\a_n=\frac{(-\pi)^n}{4^n}$

What my teacher told me :

$a_1=\frac{-\pi}{4} \approx -0.785\\
a_2=\frac{\pi^2}{16} \approx 0.617\\
a_3=\frac{-\pi^3}{64} \approx -0.484\\
a_4=\frac{\pi^4}{256} \approx 0.380\\$

So the sequence diverges. But I'm not really sure about the answer.

Here is my teacher's work:

[image: Here's my teacher's work]

Comment: @Clclstdnt: this is a *sequence*, not a *series*. No alternating series test.

Comment: One would not simply list four terms and claim the sequence is divergent or convergent. You may have probably taken a wrong note on what your teacher said.

Comment: @user587192 I just attached her work

Comment: @airlangga: Your teacher's point is that $\frac{\pi}{4}<1$. And the sequence **converges**.

Answer (score 3):

By triangle inequality one has that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n  = 0$. Thus, if $a_n = \frac{(- \pi )^n }{4^n } = \frac{ (-1)^n \pi^n }{4^n} $. Observe that

$$ \left| \frac{ (-1)^n \pi^n }{4^n}  \right| = \frac{ \pi^n }{4^n} = \left( \frac{ \pi }{4} \right)^n \to 0 $$

Answer (score 3):

Well: $$|t|<1\to \lim_{n\to\infty}t^n=0$$